# Magento charity coupon code + then ask for which charity (2 step discount for Round Table)

Tags: magento

We have a special couponcode 10% off, 3 monhts valid.

Now the 10% goes to charity. And we use the couponcode to identify that it is in fact for charity BUT alas someone has thought up that everybody can decide for themselves which chairt it is. So ....

We need a couponcode that works (check!)
But when entered somewhere there should be an extra box asking for the "charity name"

Options I can think off is directly at coupon input, or add addressfiled (but only when coupon)

Anyone know how to do this easily? or with sme code?

Comment: This will take some coding to achieve.  You may want to look into http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ to see if someone has done something similar and made it into an extension.  To custom code this would take someone a couple of hours or so.  You can easily find qualified developers to take this task on by going to: http://www.magentocommerce.com/partners/solution.  Another alternative would be to try a few things yourself and if you get stuck come back here for assistance.

Comment: seanbreeden is right - you have to enhance Magento's cart/checkout to achieve this. As he also said, you should search for a module on Magento connect. The easiest way which comes to my mind is a note at the input field for coupons (in Magento's cart) that the customer should write down his choice in the remark box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a coupon code for each charity and replace the coupon entrance input with a select box that lists your codes or make a additional select-box that pre-fills the coupon field with right code ?

Comment: There are more than 200 codes/charities. Also the charity is a number only the customer knows. So the process would be to enter general coupon code, then add additional text to specify.